# python get list of folder names from zip folder

Tags: python, zip, 7zip

I have 80 zipped files. In each of them, there are about 20 folders (that I will call first level folders). What is the python code to get a list of all of all of the first level folder names from each of the zipped file?

I need to have an excel spread sheet listing the names of the first level folders from all 80 zipped files.

Tricky part: There are 2 types of zipped files amongst those 80. Some have .zip extension while others have .7z extension.

Answer (score 0):

The [Python `zipfile` module](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile) documentaion answers your question well.

> `ZipFile.namelist()`
>
> > Return a list of archive members by name.

For 7zip, it may be necessary to use the `subprocess` module and run 7zip; not all 7zip files can be opened by the `zipfile` module.